# Cocoapods generating separate additional workspace project file?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Somewhat of an intrigue to me is how Xcode creates a new workspace project file after you make your project 'cocoapods aware' to install a pod to your current project. So the older project file has blue icon, the new one has the same name but with .workspace appended and has white icon.

I am wondering why the need to have this separate file and also if the older one without the pod is still needed by this new file?

Comment: If you haven't seen, check out this video: An Introduction to CocoaPods (Route 85) https://youtu.be/iEAjvNRdZa0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A workspace is an Xcode document that groups projects and other
>   documents so you can work on them together. A workspace can contain
>   any number of Xcode projects, plus any other files you want to
>   include. In addition to organizing all the files in each Xcode
>   project, a workspace provides implicit and explicit relationships
>   among the included projects and their targets.

Since `Cocoapods` is a library manager and install/integrate all the libraries  you want in your project. After installing pods, you have noticed that it creates a workspace that contain your project + Pods Project (this one contain all the libraries that you have installed.) as your project has dependencies on those libraries and this is how `CocoaPods` works. You can open your project with older name '.xcodeproject' but you won't be able to access the libraries as it does not contain pod.

Comment: Why can't or aren't the libraries added to the existing project though?